# Weird bug in R code: Sample Moments

Tags: r

```
CalculateSampleMomentAroundZero <- function(x) {
  # Computes the sample moments (up to fourth order) around zero
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: A vector of numbers whose sample moments around zero
  #      will be calculated
  #
  # Returns:
  #   A list that contains the sample moments (up to fourth order)
  #   of the numbers in vector x.

  n <- length(x)
  moment.zero <- lapply(1:4, function(i) (1/n) * sum(x^i))
  names(moment.zero) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")

  moment.zero
}

CalculateSampleMomentAroundMean <- function(x) {
  # Computes the sample moment (up to fourth order) around the mean
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: A vector of numbers whose sample moments around the mean 
  #      will be computed
  #
  # Returns:
  #   A list that contains the sample moments (up to fourth order) 
  #   of the numbers in vector x.

  #
  # Uses the function to calculate sample moments around zero to
  #  obtain the mean (sample moment around zero of first order) of 
  #  the numbers in vector x.
  #
  moments.around.zero <- CalculateSampleMomentAroundZero(x)
  xbar <- moments.around.zero$first

  n <- length(x)
  moment.mean <- lapply(1:4, function(i) (1/n) * sum((x - xbar)^i))
  names(moment.mean) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")

  moment.mean
} 

skewnesskurtosis <- function(x) {
  # Computes the skewness and kurtosis of a vector of numbers
  #
  # Args:
  #   x: A vector of numbers whose skewness and kurtosis will be 
  #      computed.
  #
  # Returns:
  #   A list that contains the skewness and kurtosis of the numbers 
  #   in vector x.

  #
  # Uses the function to compute sample moments around the mean to 
  #  obtain the second, third, and fourth orders of the sample    
  #  moments around the mean.
  #
  moments.around.mean <- CalculateSampleMomentAroundMean(x)
  mu2 <- moments.around.mean$second
  mu3 <- moments.around.mean$third
  mu4 <- moments.around.mean$fourth

  skew <- mu3 / (mu2)^(3/2)
  kurt <- (mu4 / (mu2)^(2)) - 3
  sk <- list(skewness = skew, kurtosis = kurt)

  sk
}
```

I checked my output by using the functions in the moments library, and I get the same results for my first function. The second function, however, is a little odd. The second, third, and fourth moments match up, but not the first. This is weird, because how could the first moment be incorrect, while the rest are right? I looked over my code many times, and I still can't find the error. Could someone please help?

Edit: here's my input and output

```
x <- rnorm(5)

CalculateSampleMomentAroundMean(x)
$first
[1] -2.220446e-17

$second
[1] 0.2923308

$third
[1] -0.02291481

$fourth
[1] 0.1172637

> moment(x, order = 1, central = TRUE)
[1] -8.326673e-18

> moment(x, order = 2, central = TRUE)
[1] 0.2923308

> moment(x, order = 3, central = TRUE)
[1] -0.02291481

> moment(x, order = 4, central = TRUE)
[1] 0.1172637
```

Comment: What is the vector you are calculating the moments for?  I did a quick test and got the right answer with `1:10` and an answer within machine precision for `sqrt(1:10)`.

Comment: I'm just using 5 random numbers generated from a normal distribution.

`> x <- rnorm(5)
> CalculateSampleMomentAroundMean(x)
$first
[1] 4.996004e-17

$second
[1] 0.05693356

$third
[1] -0.003323594

$fourth
[1] 0.007814262

> moment(x, order = 1, central = TRUE)
[1] -5.551115e-18`

Comment: The first moments don't match up for some reason.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong N's for sample moments. They are (N-n), where N is sample size and n is the degree of the moment.

Comment: No, n is the length of the vector x, so that's sample size. I think that's how the moment function in the moments library computes sample moments, too.

Comment: If you are using a library, then it is your (up to now failed) responsibility to post code for loading said library.

Comment: In addition, you need to post your inputs and outputs so we can see what "wrong" means.

Answer (score 2):

You function is calculating things correctly.  Because the calculation was performed differently in the `moments` function, the errors from the floating point representation of the numbers added up differently.

Essentially what is happening is because the machine cannot represent any given floating point number exactly, when you try to do math on a number like `sqrt(2)`, small errors are introduced.  These errors add up differently depending on what you are doing.  For example, if you multiply and then add, the floating point error may be different than if you added and then multiplied.  In any event, the error is less than a value called machine precision which is about 1e-16.  Since the differences between `moments` and your function are within that value, the difference is not meaningful.

I would suggest that if the moment is 1, you automatically return 0.  That would avoid this problem.

Comment: Have you tried generating random numbers? Sometimes my code yields the same answer, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I posted my input/output results in the original post

Comment: I ran the same code you did: `x <- rnorm(5)`.  In order for me to exactly reproduce your results, you need to set a seed before running the code.  Note that your results may change.

Comment: I used `set.seed(123)`. Did you get the same results as the moment function (in the moments library) when you ran `x <- rnorm(5)` the first time?

Comment: No, I got -2.775558e-17 for your function and -1.110223e-17 for `moments`.  Like I said, the difference is due to the order in which you performed the operations to calculate the moments compared to `moments`.  This causes slight differences in the floating point error for the two functions.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue, right? I even calculated the moments by hand, and everything but the first moment would match up.

Comment: It is only an issue because the computer cannot with 100% accuracy represent the numbers you are dealing with.  The actual code itself is just as correct as that of `moments`.  The floating point error problem is why I strongly suggest that for the first central moment, you return 0.

Comment: Ok, as long as the code itself is correct, it's all good. Thank you so much.